# Invalidate and DrawRectangle don't work together

Tags: c#, invalidation, drawrectangle

Imagine a simple .Net 2.0 Windows-Form with a MultilineTextbox that fills the whole form.
I want to (re-)draw a rectangle everytime a key is pressed. In the real application there is fare more logic about the position and stuff of the rectangle - but keep it simple.

I thought: "Lets first invalidate the TextBox and then draw the rectangle." But this doesnt work. The screen flickers shortly - thats it. If I remove the line "invaliate" a
rectangle is drawn - but the old ones keep their position..

Whats wrong? And how do I repaint from scratch?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        textBox1.Invalidate();

        using (Graphics g = this.textBox1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            int startX = 100;
            int startY = 300;
            int height = 200;

            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(60, 255, 0, 0));

            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            myPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;

            g.DrawRectangle(myPen, startX, startY, this.textBox1.Width, height);

            g.FillRectangle(brush, startX, startY, this.textBox1.Width, height);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was told to use "textBox1.Refresh()" instead of "textBox1.Invalidate();" and it works!

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //textBox1.Invalidate(); - Dont do that
    textBox1.Refresh(); //Dominik Schelenz, my internet Hero for today!

    using (Graphics g = this.textBox1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        int startX = 100;
        int startY = 300;
        int height = 200;

        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(60, 255, 0, 0));

        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        myPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;

        g.DrawRectangle(myPen, startX, startY, this.textBox1.Width, height);

        g.FillRectangle(brush, startX, startY, this.textBox1.Width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Refresh() is the same as Update()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/952964/60761). Meaning this is not an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Yes I know - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/subhagpo/archive/2005/02/22/378098.aspx - but Refresh Works and other solutions didnt - so I stick with it.

Comment: Did you test it with Invalidate caused by other events?

Answer (score 1):

Call `this.Invalidate();` on keypress, and move your drawing code to the `OnPaint` event where it is supposed to go. If you want to completely avoid flicker, you need to draw according to the following guide: [C#, double buffer in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095221/c-double-buffer-in-winforms).

You should also keep a `List<>` of all you rects and draw each one `OnPaint` as your key press is not the only thing that can invalidate the form and cause a redraw.

Comment: And how is that supposed to help? I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is flawed. `Invalidate()` only requests a repaint but it is delayed and happens *after* you draw the rectangle. So it disappears again immediately.

A short (but wrong) fix would be to replace  `Invalidate()` with `Update()`, but don't do that.

You'll have to move the drawing logic to the `textBox1.Paint` event. And your form needs a (boolean) property to decide whether to draw the Rectangle or not.

Your KeyDown should look like:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    this.DrawRect = true;
    textBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I like the short (wrong) fix because it seems to work - what's wrong about it?

Comment: Very inefficient, and you'll lose the Rect when something else Invalidates the Form.

Comment: If i press a key nothing happens. If i press the key and move the mouse over the area or out of the area- the rectangle is drawn - strange ...